# access rails instance variables in ajax and loop it

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, fullcalendar

I am building a Task Management System and have implemented fullcalendar.js in it. I need to get the pending tasks and change the color of those pending tasks. I am getting the instance variable of pending tasks details in the rails controller. But in the ajax request I am not able to loop it.

Please find my code below.

```
    $('.task_name').live('click', function () {
    alert(this.id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pending_task_details',
        data: {
            task_id: this.id
        },
        success: function (data, response, event, date) { <%
            for date_cell in @pending_tasks.start_date..@pending_tasks.end_date %> getCellFromDate(date_cell, calInstance); <% end %>
        }
    });
});
```

The above is the logic I need to implement. But I am not getting @pending_tasks.start_date in the view.

In the console I am getting the tasks details

In the tasks controller I am getting the pending tasks as.

```
  def pending_task_details
    @pending_tasks = Task.find_by_id(params[:task_id])
    p "The pending tasks are......",@pending_tasks.inspect
#(Date.parse(@pending_tasks.start_date.to_s)..Date.parse(@pending_tasks.end_date.to_s)).each { |date| render :json=>[date.strftime('%a %d %b %Y')] and return}
    render :nothing=>true 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because you are using AJAX and therefore your javascript file gets generated only once (your ruby code gets executed only when the full page is first requested).

Try downloading this example (this is working example!) and check how it's done there:

https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar

Basically you can, instead of having this:

```
$.ajax(...)
...for date_cell in @pending_tasks.start_date..@pending_tasks.end_date
```

Have this:

```
$.read(
  '/tasks/54',
  function (response) {
    // do something with task here
  }
);
// => [GET] /tasks/54
```

Check out [this](http://lyconic.com/blog/2010/08/03/dry-up-your-ajax-code-with-the-jquery-rest-plugin)
jQuery REST plugin that bokmann is using in his rails3-fullcalendar example.